# Iteratively modify pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

So this is the hideous chunk of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import h5py as hdf
def datarray(data):
    '''works well for HDF files'''
    return pd.DataFrame(np.array(data))
print( 'Modules imported')
print( 'Initialized')
pth=Path(r'C:\Users\open.Sourcerer\Desktop\1DTrimmedStruc')
geo=hdf.File(pth/'DB_RAS.g09.hdf','r')
struc=geo.get('Geometry').get('Structures').get('Attributes')
culs=geo.get('Geometry').get('Structures').get('Culvert Groups').get('Attributes')
brls=geo.get('Geometry').get('Structures').get('Culvert Groups').get('Barrels').get('Attributes')
struc=datarray(struc)
culs=datarray(culs)
brls=datarray(brls)
struc['RSReach']=struc['RS']+struc['Reach']
culs['RSReach']=culs['RS']+culs['Reach']
brls['RSReach']=brls['RS']+brls['Reach']
for df in (struc,culs,brls):
    print(df)
```

I've tried a few ways of converting these 3 datasets to dataframes and adding a column iteratively, with no success. And no, I can't merge to 1 dataset, I used to feed them to a separate function from excel, but now I'm taking the datasets straight from HDF, so the output needs to look like this specifically. How could I boil it down from here? Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: No error, but it just seems unpythonic and ugly. I'm processing each dataframe separately, imagine if they were 100 transformations to 100 dataframes, now we're looking at 10,000 lines of (hopefully unnecessary) code... or I wanted to change the incoming dataframes dynamically.